# How to have two different signup pages in rails (using devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise and the registration form shows at  /signup path but I want another page with same registration form but with different text at the top.

I can see the signup page is in /views/devise/registration/new.html.erb but how to make a copy of it and to show it at /signup_new ?

EDIT - I am using

```
devise_for :users do
   get 'signup_new', :to => 'devise/registrations#new'
end
```

and now with above code I have got the signup_new redirecting to the form but I do want some different text to be show at the top of it. How can I do it since right now, both /signup and /signup_new are pointing to same form/page. I tried to copy the new.html.erb and created signup_new.html.erb but this is not working

Comment: Do you want users to access both of these pages, or just the newer one?

Comment: @mind.blank - I want the users to access both the pages, ideally it should be same thing, I just want to show different text on one of the page, that's it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Devise view, just display different things based on the **request url**:

```
<% if request.fullpath.include?('signup_new') %>
    <%= 'text 1' %>
<% else %>
    <%= 'text 2' %>
<% end %>
```

Side note: you really should NOT have 2 different urls pointing to the same content, for Google it is called duplicate content.

Answer (score 5):

you can update your routes.rb file as..

```
 devise_for :users do
   get 'signup_new', :to => 'devise/registrations#new'      
 end
```

Comment: alright, now I have got the signup_new redirecting to the form but I do want some different text to be show at the top of it. How can I do it since right now, both /signup and /signup_new are pointing to same form/page. I tried to copy the new.html.erb and created signup_new.html.erb but this is not working

Comment: you have to override devise registration controller and add a new action called `signup_new`. then you can have your own signup_new.html.erb template in `app/views/devise/registration/`.

Comment: after override, change your routes.rb file as .. devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"} do get 'signup_new', :to => 'registrations#signup_new' end

Comment: FWIW, it looks like in order to define the additional routes you now have to use `devise_scope :user` instead of `devise_for :users`